# Error: There is already a Construct with name 'AuthCognitoUserPoolId' in TransformerRootStack [transformer-root-stack]

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify

I am attempting to deploy an app using amplify and flutter following https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-flutter-mobile-app-part-two/module-four/ tutorial and am coming across this error: There is already a Construct with name 'AuthCognitoUserPoolId' in TransformerRootStack [transformer-root-stack].

What should I do to fix this error?

I am just trying to my new data schema out to AWS and I have redone this tutorial a few times trying to see where I messed up a step.

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information that allows the community to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error when trying to `amplify push`. To fix, I needed to do an `amplify pull`. Then I was able to successfully push